# Svelte / SvelteKit importing an npm library returns error when trying to work with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to learn Svelte / SvelteKit by porting over an existing Angular application. The app should show a Leaflet map with a heatmap layer as overlay. The map part works and is robust, even when I navigate or refresh Svelte handles it fine. The heatmap on the other hand only loads when the app initializes for the first time as you can see here:

[image]

However When I refresh I get this error and the whole `Map.svelte` component doesn't load at all anymore with the following error message in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Leaflet.heatLayer is not a function
```

[image]

I suspect it has to do with the way the lifecycle handles imports, because in my Angular app the imports don't have to be done in a life cycle method in order for them to work, whereas the only way to get Leaflet to even render in SvelteKit I have to do an async import.

Can anyone clarify what's going on with the `Leaflet.heatlayer` error and how I can fix it?

**Map.svelte**

```
<script lang="ts">
    import type { HeatLayer, Map } from 'leaflet';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    let Leaflet;
    let map: Map;
    let heatLayer: HeatLayer;

    onMount(async () => {
        Leaflet = await import('leaflet');
        import('leaflet.heat');

        const heatLatLngTuple = await fetchData(); // fetchData returns data from JSON file

        const mapTiles = Leaflet.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 19,
            attribution: '© OpenStreetMap'
        });

        heatLayer = Leaflet.heatLayer(heatLatLngTuple, {. // THIS LINE IS CAUSING THE ERROR
            radius: 20,
            blur: 25,
            minOpacity: 0,
            maxZoom: 6,
            max: 12
        });

        map = Leaflet.map('map', {
            center: [51.505, -0.09],
            zoom: 6,
            layers: [mapTiles, heatLayer]
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="map" />
```

**Things I've tried:**

- including 'leaflet-heat.js' from **node_modules** in a `<script>` tag in **`app.html`**
- including 'leaflet-heat.js' from **node_modules** in a `<script>` tag in **`__layout.svelte`**
- including 'leaflet-heat.js' from **node_modules** in a `<script>` tag in **`index.svelte`**
- importing `leaflet.heat` at the top of `Map.svelte` with "import 'leaflet.heat'" <- THIS WORKED IN ANGULAR! but here it just results in this error

```
ReferenceError: window is not defined
```

- putting a tick() before assigning `heatLayer` in `Map.svelte`

**Resources:**

- [My GitHub repo](https://github.com/florestankorp/leaflet-playground)
- [Leaflet.heat](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat)

Answer (score 1):

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69894352/4026317) points out there is an additional way of importing that I didn't know about using 
[vite-plugin-iso-import](https://github.com/bluwy/vite-plugin-iso-import)

After getting that set up my component now works and after importing "leaflet.heat" with `?client` added and moved to the top level of my imports. Here is the [link to the FAQ](https://kit.svelte.dev/faq#integrations-how-do-i-use-a-client-side-only-library-that-depends-on-document-or-window) with a detailed explanation.

After the changes my component now looks like this:

**Map.svelte**

```
<script lang="ts">
    import type { HeatLayer, Map } from 'leaflet';
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import Leaflet from 'leaflet?client'; // provides definition of 'L' needed by Leaflet
    import 'leaflet.heat?client'; // Note the '?client' after the module name which makes sure 'leaflet.heat' always has access to the 'window' object

    let map: Map;
    let heatLayer: HeatLayer;

    onMount(async () => {
        const heatLatLngTuple = await fetchData(); 

        const mapTiles = Leaflet.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            maxZoom: 19,
            attribution: '© OpenStreetMap'
        });

        heatLayer = Leaflet.heatLayer(heatLatLngTuple, {. // THIS LINE IS CAUSING THE ERROR
            radius: 20,
            blur: 25,
            minOpacity: 0,
            maxZoom: 6,
            max: 12
        });

        map = Leaflet.map('map', {
            center: [51.505, -0.09],
            zoom: 6,
            layers: [mapTiles, heatLayer]
        });
    });
</script>

<div id="map" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue on refresh, you need import the module inside the on mount. It's not the same as your code. But you get that point.

```js
    onMount(async () => {

        const leafletModule = await import('leaflet');
        L = leafletModule.default;
```